# Firebase Storage public URL Access Denied ( I need a permanent URL with public access ) makePublic()

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

if mishandling  When Access token revoked GetdownloadURL() will invalid. Hence I need a public access permanent URL without access token. **How to** `makePublic()` something did mistake but I can't conclude, `gcs.bucket("Project-12345.appspot.com").file(fileName).makePublic()`

Security Rules

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o { 
    match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read;
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }}}
```

Mycode

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const serviceAccount = require('./ProjectID-12345-firebase-adminsdk-.json');
    admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
       databaseURL: "https://ProjectID-12345.firebaseio.com"     
    });
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const gcs = new Storage({
        projectId: "projectId-12345",
        keyFilename: serviceAccount
    });

    const GetUrl = (productId) => {
        const ImgList = ["ImgA_650x650", "ImgB_650x650", "ImgC_650x650", "ImgD_650x650"] ;
        let url = []
        ImgList.forEach( (element , Index) =>{
             let fileName = "product/"+ productId + "/resize"+ element;
             let storageref = gcs.bucket("Project-12345.appspot.com").file(fileName);
             storageref.makePublic();
             url[Index] = storageref.publicUrl();
        })
        return url;
     }
```

I get URL without Access token

> [
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com/Project-12345.appspot.com/product/1zHTmjNc5CV4WBLDLgdV/resizeImgA_650x650',
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com/Project-12345.appspot.com/product/1zHTmjNc5CV4WBLDLgdV/resizeImgB_650x650',
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com/Project-12345.appspot.com/product/1zHTmjNc5CV4WBLDLgdV/resizeImgC_650x650',
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com/Project-12345.appspot.com/product/1zHTmjNc5CV4WBLDLgdV/resizeImgD_650x650'
> ]

But the issue is the URL is access denied. it Show error as

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related with fact that `makePublic()` is asynchronous and in the presented code its use in synchronus way and as the results `publicUrl()`, which is synchronous, is executed before it.

`makePublic()` should be used with `await` in `async` function like:

```
const GetUrl = async (productId) => { 
...
   await storageref.makePublic();
...
```

or with `then` like:

```
storageref.makePublic().then(() => url[Index] = storageref.publicUrl());
```

or with callback.

Of course please treat is as pseudo code. I am not sure if you can just copy paste it and it will work, anyway for sure the function is asynchronous and have to be coded that way. There are nice examples in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#makePublic).

Comment: Thanking  you for help to resolve me issue. Your sheared   document [link] 
[ https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#makePublic ] is really helpful for me. When call mackPublic()  now I am notice some error also  as  **"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object"** . I have tried  update `run-script` , delete and reinstall node. But still I have  same error

Comment: If there is different error you may post new question with new version of code.